# Looping files in directory in reverse order

Tags: windows, batch-file, command-prompt

In DOS batch file I can write following loop to iterate files in a directory in alphabetical ascending order:

```
for %f in (*) do (echo %f)
```

How do I do the same but iterate files in reverse order (alphabetical descending) ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the command line:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %f in ('dir /b /o-n') do (echo %f)
```

In a bat file:

```
for /f "tokens=*" %%f in ('dir /b /o-n') do (echo %%f)
```

---

```
/B           Uses bare format (no heading information or summary).
/O           List by files in sorted order.
sortorder    N  By name (alphabetic)
             -  Prefix to reverse order

Type "dir /?" in CMD for more details
```

Comment: Filenames can have leading spaces - and `tokens=*` strips leading spaces.  It's always better to use `"delims="` if the filename needs to be accurate.

Comment: @foxidrive - Amen to that. I've never understood why so many people use "TOKENS=*" when in reality they want "DELIMS=".

Comment: The simple FOR loop returns only files, but the DIR command as written will return both files and folders. The `/A-D` option should be added to eliminate folders. To really make it like the simple FOR, it should have `/A-D-H-S` to also eliminate hidden and system files.